# understanding of method for confidence interval in regression

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

I read this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27133462), and at the end of page 841 there is this sentence:

```
demonstrating that state transitions exert a differential 
effect across the firing rate spectrum (slope, 95% confidence interval 0.66–0.71)
```

What really means the value `0.66–0.71`? How it is obtained?
I couldn't find more detail in the article...

Thanks a lot

***EDIT*** : Extract from the paper:

[image]
(B) Differential effect of brain state on neurons of different firing rates. Comparison of the firing rates (log scale) of the same pyramidal neurons during WAKE and
nonREM—each point is the same neuron in two states. During nonREM, neurons at the right end of the distribution are decreased, but neurons at the left end of
the distribution increase their rates compared to WAKE (arrows).

Comment: What is the response variable of the model? What type of model was calculated (a linear regression?)

Comment: @MichaelM: I edit the post with the corresponding figure of the paper

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+coefficient+confidence+interval+score%3A2

Comment: @whuber : thanks for these links, but it remains unclear for what was done in this specific article.

Comment: I believe some of the links are explicit about the construction of the confidence intervals.  This is such a standard procedure--the intervals often are automatically reported by least-squares regression software--that one can feel comfortable that the accounts in the duplicate answers describe what the paper's authors did.